# How to prevent the stripping of symbols using the xcodebuild archive action?

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, debug-symbols, google-breakpad

On my hand is an Xcode project, comprising of a number of static libraries, and an iOS application that consumes them (we do not intend to release the libraries). Part of it is a crash reporting implementation based on Google Breakpad.

An issue that we've found is that we aren't getting line number information in crash reports for the libraries, from our releases. These are generated using `xcodebuild archive -project ${PROJECT_PATH} -scheme ${SCHEME_NAME} -archivePath ${OUTPUT_PATH} -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -IDEBuildingContinueBuildingAfterErrors=YES`. EDIT: using Xcode 12.

**If, instead of `archive`, I run the `xcodebuild build` action with the same options** (exc. `archivePath` of course) - or build the project in the IDE -, **then I get complete symbol information and everything works** (at least testing on iOS Simulator). This seems to be the only difference - of course then I'd still need to produce an .ipa somehow.

The build options are shared between all libraries and application, and include the following:

```
COPY_PHASE_STRIP = YES
DEPLOY_POSTPROCESSING = YES
SEPARATE_STRIP = YES        # tried to change each of these to NO in various permutations; no difference.
STRIP_STYLE = non-global
```

What is the difference between the steps that the `build` and the `archive` actions perform, with regards to stripping?

How can I create the .ipa from the artifact of the `xcodebuild build`, *or* otherwise coerce `xcodebuild archive` to omit / delay stripping, so that I may perform that manually once I've dumped the symbols?

It might be worth mentioning that I've tried combinations of the `xcodebuild` actions as well, i.e. `clean build archive` in one or separate steps - makes no difference.

(FWIW, I realise that the `PackageApplication` command of `xcrun` was deprecated as of Xcode 8.3.)